# Change color / size of average in boxplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm wondering how to change color and size of of the average mark of a box plot.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.statistics}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[] %
   \addplot+[%
    mark = *, %
    boxplot = {%
     average = auto,%
     every average/.style={/tikz/mark=diamond*},%
    }, %
   ] table [row sep=\\, y index = 0] {.2\\.2\\ .3\\ .4\\ .4\\.4\\.4\\.4\\.4\\.9\\};
  \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is the output for me:
[image: Output]

I'd like the diamond for the average to be larger and red. How can this be done?

Comment: You can use `every average/.style={/tikz/mark=diamond*,mark size=3},`.Problem:color. Im looking for color `red`(at the moment not working)...

Comment: I think that is a duplicate question of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/244159/95441. Unfortunately also there nobody has given an answer so far.